# I need to build a junit test from this java code

Tags: java, junit

```
public class Robot extends Monster {
    int x;
    int y;
    int power;

    public Robot (int x, int y, int power){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.power = power;
    }

    @Override
    public double areaOfDestruction() {
        return power * power;
    }

    @Override
    public double move(int dx, int dy, int terrain_type) {

        if (terrain_type == 1) {
            dx = dx / 2;
            dy = dy / 2;
            x = dx + x;
            y = dy + y;
        }
        else if (terrain_type == 0) {
            dx = dx * 2;
            dy = dy * 2;
            x = dx + x;
            y = dy + y;
        }
        else {
            dx = dx + x;
            dy = dy + y;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So i've written tests for area of destruction but i'm trying to write tests for the move function and here is what i have so far for the test for the move()

```
    void move() {
        Robot testSubject = new Robot(5, 5, 10);
        double robotMove = testSubject.move(2,2,0);
        
    }
```

This code above is the test that i have written so far and im trying my best to figure out how exactly to write this test.

Comment: The problem is that calling the `move` method on your `Robot` class has no discernible effect (as far as we can see from your question, because you haven't shown us the `Monster` class). That is, there's no other method you can call whose behaviour is affected by the implementation of move. It literally doesn't matter what the body of move does.

Comment: Just print the new values?

Comment: Although as your fields are not private, if your test is in the same package as Robot (as it should be), you can simply check the new values of x and y in your test

Comment: Just do a quick JUnit tutorial online it will help you alot. Basically you need a add a RobotTest class which has a lot of methods annotated with @Test which test all the flows in your Robot class